# Can admin username and application's user username be same?

Tags: php, database, sqlite, web, database-design

I'm confuse about login and register system between user and admin, for example, Admin have the username "andy1234" but the user want to create a username with "andy1234" too. So, should I accept username of admin and username of user can have the same value in my Database? If it can, should I use "unique filtered index" in Mysql ?, because I'm doing with MariaDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't accept it, it can make troubleshooting more difficult later.

i.e. User wants to reset password because he forgot it. Who's password should be updated?

You can really create workarounds for this, but why add complexity?

About the index, it's common to use a unique index to separate this even with particular usernames (a.k.a. ID). I don't really know why, but i think it's because in some systems the username can be renamed. Using an ID guarantees that the row has it's identifier even if the user is renamed.